# Getting text between first occurance of two strings [Shell]

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have a feed.xml file that looks something like this. What I want to do is to grab the test.html from this feed.(Basically, the top most item's url.) Any thoughts on how to do this?

```
<rss>
<item>
    <title>ABC</title>
    <url>
        test.html
    </url>
</item>
<item>
    <title>CDE</title>
    <url>
        test1.html
    </url>
</item>
</rss>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do in shell only? Better to use some XML parser.

Comment: It's a part of a much bigger post build script and needs to be done in shell unfortunately.

Comment: Have your script invoke a program that uses an XML parser.  Really.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure is fixed and you know that the URL has the postfix .html, you can simply do:

```
  cat <yourfile> | grep ".html" | head -n1
```

If you don't know the postfix (or the string "html" can exist before), you can do:

```
 cat <yourfile> | grep -A1 "<url>" | head -n2 | tail -n1
```

**EDIT**
In case, the structure is not fixed (i.e., no newlines), there this

```
 cat <yourfile> | grep -o "<url>[^<]*</url>" | head -n1 | cut -d'>' -f2 | cut -d'<' -f1
```

or that

```
 cat <yourfile> | grep -o "<url>[^<]*</url>" | head -n1 | sed -E -e"s#<url>(.*)</url>#\1#"
```

may work.

Comment: The .html thing works fine if the file looks exactly like the post above, but if there are no new line characters: <item><title>ABC</title><url>test.html</url></item><item><title>CDE</title><url>test1.html</url></item>, It doesn't work.

Comment: That is what I meant whith 'fixed structure'. I edited my answer for this case.

Comment: If you have GNU grep, `grep -m 1 -o '[-_.A-Zza-z0-9]*\.html' file` give or take a few characters in the character class depending on what type of file name you are trying to match.

Comment: @tripleee I know that the `cat`command is not really needed here, but it allows to write the needed stuff as a pipe, thus you can get your stream from somewhere else. The OP did not state, where it input comes from.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
 sed '/<url>/,/<\/url>/{//d;s/ *//;q};d' file.xml
```

Comment: Throws error: sed: 1: "/<url>/,/<\/url>/{//d;s ...": extra characters at the end of q command

Comment: I'm not sure why but perhaps you are running an old version of sed, try: `sed -e '/<url>/,/<\/url>/!d' -e '//d' -e 's/ *//' -e 'q' file`

Comment: I've no idea why. What OS and sed version are you using? I noticed you used `"`'s rather than `'`'s to surround the commands may be this has an unwanted side effect.

Comment: Mac OSX 10.7. I did use '. The error just came back like that.  $ sed -e '/<url>/,/<\/url>/!d' -e '//d' -e 's/ *//' -e 'q' test.xml 
</item>

Comment: I believe Mac use a BSD version of sed. I am on Linux, so I can't test any further. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

This awk script should work:

```
awk '/<url>/ && url==0 {url=1;next;} {if(url==1) {print;url=2;}}' file
```

**EDIT:**

Following grep command might also work:

```
grep -m 1 "^ *<url>" -A1 file | grep -v "<url>"
```

Comment: What if the <url> tag looks something like <bundle:releaselink>

Comment: In that case just replace `<url>` with `<bundle:releaselink>` in both commands.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using line-based tools, I'd suggest using an xsl transform to get the data you want out of the document without making assumptions about the way it's formatted.

If you save this to `get-url.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xsl:output method="text"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(rss/item/url)"/>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then you can get the value of `url` from `feed.xml` like this:

```
$ xsltproc get-url.xsl feed.xml; echo
test.html
$
```

The extra `echo` is just there to give you a newline after the end of the output, to make it friendly for an interactive shell. Just remove it if you're assigning the result to a shell variable with `$()`.

Comment: How would you create the xsl if the url tag was replaced with <bundle:releaselink>

Comment: @user754905 if your input contains `<bundle:releaselink>`, then the root element of the input should contain the attribute `xmlns:bundle="..."`. You need to copy that `xmlns:bundle="..."` attribute into the root element of the xsl (i.e. the `xsl:stylesheet` element), and then replace `rss/item/url`  with `rss/item/bundle:releaselink`.